# Selenium read a table and write into a file line by line

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am looking for the help to read a table span using selenium code and write span into the file,
following is my html code

```
<table>
<tbody><tr>
<tr>
<td><span>
FIRST
</span>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<span>SECOND</span>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<span>THIRD</span>
</td>
</tr>
<tbody>
</table>
```

I need to write FIRST SECOND THIRD  on a file in java.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you have located/found the *table* WebElement. Then you can get span elements content like this:

```
List<WebElement> spanElements = tableElement.findElements(By.ByTagName("span"));

for (WebElement element : spanElements) {
    String spanContent = element.getText();
    //save it to a collection or a StringBuilder, then write it to a file
}
```

Having a look at [this](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html) and [this](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.ByTagName.html) might help.

Comment: Thanks for the response Sergio. +1

Comment: You are welcome! I answered on the run, so there was a mistake in the code, though it seems that you understood the idea anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

1) XPath that gets all text is:

```
//span/text()
```

2) in java code you may type something like

```
String text = selenium.getText("xpath=//span");
```